# How to fetch the initial data from firebase with redux and react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I have a simple `create react app`, it has a component called `List`.

That List component loads some data at page load, by dispatching a redux action called `handleInitialData`

I also have a firebase `database`, it has some dummy data. And I want to load that data with a `useeffect` hook that dispatches the action `handleInitialData` that should trigger the firebase function to get the data from the firebase.

I am new to firebase but from what I understand, the way to get data is by doing something like this:

```
  listsRef.on("value", snapshot => {
     console.log(snapshot.val())
  })
```

And this is exactly what I am doing inside of the `handleInitialData` action:

```
export const handleInitialData = () => async dispatch => {
  listsRef.on("value", snapshot => {
  dispatch(receiveLists(snapshot.val()))
  })
}
```

But this is not doing anything.

In fact it never goes inside the body of `listsref.on`

Any ideas on what is wrong here?

This is my component:

```
const List = ({dispatch, addList, lists}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(handleInitialData())
  },[dispatch])


  return (
    <div>
      {lists.lists.map((x, i) => <p key={i}>{x.name}</p>)}
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = ({lists}) => {
  return {
    lists,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(List);
```

My lists reducer:

```
import {RECEIVE_LISTS} from '../actions/lists';

export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_LISTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.lists
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My firebase setup:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  databaseURL: "xxx",
  ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

firebase.analytics();

const databaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
export const listsRef = databaseRef.child("lists")
```

Comment: Did you check your JavaScript console for any relevant errors?

Comment: yes.. nothing important there.

Comment: Please be a bit more descriptive on what *does* happen, as it's unlikely someone can help with the current information. For example: if you place a breakpoint on `dispatch(receiveLists(snapshot.val()))` and run the code in a debugger, does it ever hit that breakpoint?